# UIPageControllerView recycle pages reducing memory usage

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I am trying to implement Pagecontroller to show images in horizontal order. But memory goes higher and higher after each swipe. Any solution for reducing memory usage?
I have 100 images that each of them nearly 200kb. But memory usages goes up to 800mb while scrolling.

Note : It gives memory warning on real device but app does not crush.

Here are the classes that I have used for controlling pages.

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    // MARK: - Variables
    private var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    var contentImages = [String]()
    // Initialize it right away here

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for index in 0...93 {
           contentImages.append("pages-\(index).jpg")
        }

        createPageViewController()
        setupPageControl()
    }

    private func createPageViewController() {

        let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as UIPageViewController
        pageController.dataSource = self

        if contentImages.count > 0 {
            let firstController = getItemController(0)!
            let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
            pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

        pageViewController = pageController
        addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
        self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
        pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    private func setupPageControl() {
        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    }

    // MARK: - UIPageViewControllerDataSource

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < contentImages.count {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController? {

        if itemIndex < contentImages.count {
            let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemController") as PageItemController
            pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
            pageItemController.imageName = contentImages[itemIndex]
            return pageItemController
        }

        return nil
    }

    // MARK: - Page Indicator

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return contentImages.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

}
```

Item Controller

```
import UIKit

class PageItemController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Variables
    var itemIndex: Int = 0
    var imageName: String = "" {

        didSet {

            if let imageView = contentImageView {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }

        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var contentImageView: UIImageView?

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contentImageView!.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the app crash at some point because of too much memory usage? Or does it hit a limit and frees memory?

Comment: Actually it does not crush , but 800 - 900 mb memory usage is not good I think or not ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an UIImage with imageNamed the image will be cached. You can try some of the other constructor methods without caching. But usually the image caching just works.

For example you could try [NSBundle.pathForResource(_:ofType:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:) and [UIImage.init(contentsOfFile:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithContentsOfFile:).

Or you have some kind of memory leak in the code. I don't know enough Swift to spot any in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What's going on here is that UIImage(named:) is caching your image data forever. It's really, seriously, meant to be used only for things that are a) small b) frequently used c) essential to your interface.

In Objective-C you can get at the internal method +_flushSharedImageCache on memory warning, or you could call the internal +removeImageNameFromCache(imageName) when your controller is dealloc'd, if there's some really really good reason to not bother writing your own cache.

But in Swift, just write your own cache and keep a max of a handful of most recently used images in it, it's easy. Here's how I dealt with this kind of problem back when iPhones had 128MB RAM: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/